# .htaccess Force Trailing Slash Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

Apologies but I'm fairly new to URL Rewrites. I've managed to get the rewrite working in the conventional sense but cannot force it to have a trailing slash.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash for non-files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [L]
```